# "Deprecated" notation for Sun's C++ compiler?

Tags: c++, deprecated, suncc

Does the Sun compiler have a notation to mark functions as deprecated, like GCC's `__attribute__ ((deprecated))` or MSVC's `__declspec(deprecated)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that one solution that would work on **any** compiler that supports `#warning` would be:

- Copy the header in question to a new, promoted header name
- Remove the deprecated functions from the promoted header file
- Add to the old header file: **`#warning "This header is deprecated.  Please use {new header name}"`**

Answer (score 1):

This will get you a compiler warning on sun with the "+w" flag or on gcc with the "-Wall" flag. Unfortunately it breaks the ABI compatibility of the function; I haven't discovered a way around that yet.

```
#define DEPRECATED char=function_is_deprecated()

inline char function_is_deprecated()
{
    return 65535;
}

void foo(int x, DEPRECATED)
{
}

int main()
{
    foo(3);
    return 0;
}
```

The output:

```
CC -o test test.cpp +w
"test.cpp", line 7: Warning: Conversion of "int" value to "char" causes truncation.
"test.cpp", line 15:     Where: While instantiating "function_is_deprecated()".
"test.cpp", line 15:     Where: Instantiated from non-template code.
1 Warning(s) detected.
```

The way you use it is when you want to declare a function deprecated, you add a comma to the end of its parameter list and write DEPRECATED. The way it works under the hood is it adds a default argument (thus preserving API) that causes the conversion warning.

Comment: Seems that the template argument <LINE> went missing somewhere.

Comment: I was thinking wrong about when the template argument would get evaluated so I got rid of it.